# How to get Business days per month between two dates?

Tags: date

I need to get the total Business Days Per MONTH between 2 dates. I would like to incorporate a Holidays table too.

For Example,

```
@StartDate = '12/26/2013'
@EndDate ='03/19/2014'
```

I need the following

Month          BusinessDays
December 2013       4
January 2014        21
February 2014       19
March 2014      13

I found this thread which does the days per month but not the BUSINESS/WOrking days.

[How to get the total days per month between two dates?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18626/how-to-get-the-total-days-per-month-between-two-dates/108688#108688)

Any Help would be greatly appreaciated.

thanks

Tania

Comment: What platform are you using?

Comment: Here's two ways to do it

Sql
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252519/count-work-days-between-two-dates

Oracle:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14898357/calculate-business-days-in-oracle-sqlno-functions-or-procedure

Comment: This is really something that's easy to google. Of the two questions suggested by @MattD, for instance, the SQL Server one was the top result for me when I googled for `count business days sql server`.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your response. I have seen the Business/Working  Day Calc in the link you provided but none of them give me a "by month Result". If I have a Date range of Jan 12, 2015 to April 26th 2015, I need the result to show working days per month of Jan, Feb, March and April. thanks.